# Adding a bookmark link to a Facebook IFRAME app

Tags: jquery, facebook, xfbml

I have a simple IFRAME based facebook app, with everything set up for XFBML (it's working by the way), and I want a link to add a Facebook bookmark. It sounds simple but it really doesn't seem to be.

doesn't show anything, even though other tags render, so I was looking at doing it with a link instead, the way the Facebook developer app does at the top.

If I user a link to

"http://www.facebook.com/fbml/ajax/uiserver.php?method=bookmark.add&app_id=XXX&display=async"

Then I can open the bookmark form in a full window, but what I really want is to do it in an ajax pop-up, the way Facebook and the developer app do. However when I call the same url with $.get from Jquery it displays nothing.

Any ideas? What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

All you should have to do is use `<fb:bookmark></fb:bookmark>`. More information here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/#bookmarks

Under "bookmarks and counters". Or is that maybe what you had above, but the tag got stripped out of your question?

Comment: What's with the iproxy.saverpigeeks in the URI you put in?

Comment: I know this is years old, but just looked back at this old question, and saw the comment about the proxy, no idea where that came from. I don't remember where I got that link. I might have ended up on that link by following a link on another site, and just copied and pasted it, and didn't look closely at it. Very sorry if it caused any confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that this is a known Facebook bug that was first reported in April:

http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=11423

They haven't gotten to it yet, and it's currently assigned their lowest priority, but I'm sure some more votes on the issue wouldn't hurt.

In the meantime, I haven't tested this but a workaround appears to be showing an image of the bookmark and doing the dialog JavaScript yourself (from [www.devcomments.com/trouble-with-fb-bookmark-to182399.htm](http://www.devcomments.com/trouble-with-fb-bookmark-to182399.htm)):

```
<img src="bookmark.png" onclick="FB.Connect.showBookmarkDialog()" style="cursor:pointer;" />
```